# Python argparse help option in a mutually_exclusive_group

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

The [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse) module for Python 2.7 includes a command line **help** option, that by default prints a usage message whenever `-h` or `--help` is present in the command line options. By default, the help option can be passed in with any other command line options. For example:

```
script.py [-h] [-opt1 arg1 | -opt2 arg2]
```

If the `-h` optional argument exists, all other args are ignored and the help message is printed.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that `-h` has to be used alone, like can be done with any other optional arg by placing it within a `mutually_exclusive_group`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what will you do if they violate this constraint? Print the help? :)

Comment: @KennyOstrom That is ...(wince)... probably the most logical thing to do. Hmm.

Comment: My thoughts too haha. Well you can set `add_help` to `False` and define your own process with the `-h` flag.

Comment: @busybear I see the `add_help=False` parameter in the docs now. Thanks. To me, it seems consistent that `-h` should be used alone, but as Kenny pointed out, it's kind of a moot point!

Comment: The default `--help` argument is of class `argparse._HelpAction`.  Its `__call__` method does a `parse.print_help()` followed by a `parser.exit()`.  So whenever the parser encounters the '-h' string, this is executed.  The `exit` bypasses the normal ending of `parse_args()`.  Your custom help can draw ideas from this as needed.

Comment: Imagine your user starts writing a command line and then has some sort of question or unknown.  They can add a '-h' to bailout and ask for help.  No need to delete all the previous strings.  The help request has priority regardless of how much they've written so far.  This behavior is somewhat modified when using subparsers.

Comment: What you want is what I would expect one should be able to add -h to any command and have that command not only produce help but it could even emphasize the parts of help that relates to the other arguments. The text output that occurs with -h without other arguments should be the same as with arguments when piped to a non-tty.